# Nameserver record keeps getting added to DNS zone in Windows Server DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2019, dns-zone, dns-server

I have a public DNS server running on a Windows server with the hostname `dc01`.

A nameserver for this hostname (`dc01`) keeps getting added to the DNS zone:

[image]

If I try to delete it, then reload the zone and refresh; the record is immediately recreated.

Running a [DNS check](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3aincredibleit.uk&run=toolpage) for my domain name on MX Toolbox shows an RFC 1035 violation for [Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/dns/dns-primary-server-listed-at-parent) in that Windows DNS Server is publishing 3 records, but only 2 records are listed at the parent DNS server (`ns1` and `ns2`).

I could fix this by adding `dc01` as a nameserver record in my parent DNS server (domain registrar), but I don't actually want 3 nameservers - I just want the 2.

**How can I prevent Windows DNS Server from creating the `dc01` NS-record?**

---

<sub>As an aside, I know that the 2 nameservers should be on separate IP's.</sub>

<sup>Also, the following changes have been made to DC01 and the DNS Server service was subsequently restarted:</sup>

<sup>DNS > Zone > General > Dynamic Updates = None</sup>

<sup>NIC > Properties > Advanced > DNS > Register this connection's addresses in DNS = Unchecked (disabled)</sup>

<sup>`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters\RegisterDnsARecords` = `0`</sup>

<sup>`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters\PublishAddresses` = `116.202.233.75`</sup>

<sup>These changes prevent the internal `192.x.x.x` IP address for DC01 from being published publicly to the world in the zone as an A-record. Instead the external public IP is published to the `dc01` A-record.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139040/discussion-on-question-by-danny-beckett-nameserver-record-keeps-getting-added-to).

Answer (score 1):

Each DNS zone should have SOA record
containing administrative information about the zone.

In SOA record there is domain-name of the name server that was the original or primary source of data for this zone - primary server.

In your case Windows DNS server forces zone to have NS record for the primary server specified in the SOA.

Change primary server name in SOA from `dc01.incredibleit.uk` to `ns1.incredibleit.uk` (or ns2) to get rid of `dc01.incredibleit.uk` in the Name Servers list.